# Bug Reporting: After updating MikTex from 20.6.29 to 20.11 Physical Review Letters template became broken

Tags: revtex

After updating to 20.11  pdflatex, called from TexStudio, exits with error

! Extra \endgroup.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Version 20.6.29 works fine.
Both version was tested on Win7 and Win10 x64.
File  prl.tex for test placed on https://cloud.mail.ru/public/7K2F/5CGYz1ahD

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it works in texlive, but miktex seems to be missing an update. I will check.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it has been updated but it is in the obsolete tree on ctan, so miktex probably ignored it.

Comment: @boristim Why don't you use a current revtex4-2 instead of the old revtex4?

Comment: Why did the program, installed on November 08, stop working on November 15 without announcing a reason?
Did I spend a day realising it was because of ther upgrade?

Comment: I have no idea what you did on november 15 to trigger the error.  miktex can neither know that you are using a  obsolete class from 2001 nor warn you if it stops working. And you didn't need to spend a day on it: As you can see it tooks us only 10 minutes to tell you what is going on, so next time ask earlier.

Comment: On November 15, I helped a friend install MikTex on Windows 10. His file returned an error. The same file was running on the MikTex installed on Windows 7 on my computer on November 8. The first idea was the OS difference. I installed another copy on Windows 10. Does not work. I spent a long time digging in logs and in the registry, trying to understand the difference. And only after a (random) update of the MikTeX on Windows 7, when the file stopped working too, it became clear that it was dangerous to update.